# Modern Webpage Screen Capture using Python, Selenium & PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to capture a modern design web page. Below is my code -

```
def do_screen_capturing(url, screen_path, width, height):
    print("Capturing screen for.. "+url)
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.set_script_timeout(60)
    if width and height:
        driver.set_window_size(width, height)
    driver.get(url)
    # print(driver)
    driver.execute_script('function whatever(){var a=document.body,b=document.documentElement,c=Math.max(a.scrollHeight,a.offsetHeight,b.clientHeight,b.scrollHeight,b.offsetHeight);window.scrollTo(0,c);var d=Math.max(a.scrollHeight,a.offsetHeight,b.clientHeight,b.scrollHeight,b.offsetHeight);c!=d&&whatever()}whatever();')
    time.sleep(1)
    el = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    for i in range(1,100,1):
       el.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script('function whatever(){var a=document.body,b=document.documentElement,c=Math.max(a.scrollHeight,a.offsetHeight,b.clientHeight,b.scrollHeight,b.offsetHeight);window.scrollTo(0,c);var d=Math.max(a.scrollHeight,a.offsetHeight,b.clientHeight,b.scrollHeight,b.offsetHeight);c!=d&&whatever()}whatever();')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 0);')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.save_screenshot(screen_path)
    print("Screenshot taken!")
    driver.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
    driver.quit()
```

When I use Firefox (on my local machine) as driver then I get a beautiful screenshot. Take a look at the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/wpvJ1no.png) taken using Firefox as driver. I have cropped the screenshot because it was too big in size.

The problem is when I use PhantomJS. Seems like it does not execute those JS scripts that I have added. Take a look at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoyqV.png) taken using PhantomJS as driver.

Website tested - https://www.kitandace.com/ca/en/

Is there a way to make PhantomJS perform similar to Firefox?

Comment: PhantomJS is a different browser and you likely haven't tested your website for compatibility with PhantomJS. Have you tried to wait a little bit in your PhantomJS script before taking the screenshot?

Comment: You can check the code included in my post. I tried waiting as well using time.sleep().